# MPI_Reduce doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi, reduction

I am very new to MPI and I'm trying to use MPI_Reduce to find the maximum of an integer array. I have an integer array `arr` of size `arraysize`, and here is my code:

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &number_of_processes);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_process_id);
MPI_Bcast(arr, arraysize, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Reduce(arr, &result, arraysize, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(!my_process_id){
    printf("%d", result);
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

My program compiles and runs on 8 processes with no problems, however, nothing gets printed on the screen. For debugging purposes, I change the conditional to `if(my_process_id)` (without `!`) and run. Then I get a weird output such as `00030000` where 3 could be anywhere in this list nondeterministically. 3 is my array's first value (but not the maximum). I know about parallel programming in general (not expert, but I usually know what I am doing) but I am very new to MPI to I may be doing an obvious mistake. All the tutorials that I've seen online have code samples similar to mine, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks,

Can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPI_Reduce` works exactly the way it is supposed to work. You are the one who does not use it the way it is supposed to be used.

`MPI_Reduce` performs *element-wise* reduction of data, distributed among the ranks in the MPI job. Both the source and the destination buffers should be arrays of size `arraysize`, e.g.:

```
int arr[arraysize];
int result[arraysize];

// Fill local arr with meaningful data
...
// Perform reduction
MPI_Reduce(arr, result, arraysize, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

What `MPI_Reduce` does is the following:

```
result[0] = max(arr_0[0], arr_1[0], ..., arr_(N-1)[0]);
result[1] = max(arr_0[1], arr_1[1], ..., arr_(N-1)[1]);
...
result[arraysize-1] = max(arr_0[arraysize-1], ..., arr_(N-1)[arraysize-1]);
```

where `arr_0` is the copy of `arr` in rank 0, `arr_1` is the copy of `arr` in rank 1, and so on.

The combination of `MPI_Bcast`, followed by a reduction with `MPI_MAX` does *aboslutely nothing* since all copies of `arr` would have the same values after the broadcast and the aplication of an element-wise `max` reduction would simply yield the same values. Worse, I would presume that `result` in your code is a scalar integer variable, hence `MPI_Reduce` would overwrite `arraysize-1` elements past `result` and would most likely destroy the stack frame, overwrite the value of `my_process_id` in rank `0` so it would not be `0` anymore (hence nothing is printed) and crashing rank `0` afterwards. Of course, it all depends on how the local variables are aranged in the stack - the implications might not be as severe as I have described them.

If you'd like to find the maximum value of an array, you should first distribute it using `MPI_Scatter`, then use `MPI_Reduce` to perform element-wise reduction and then perform another reduction on the result:

```
int elements_per_proc = arraysize/number_of_processes;
int arr[arraysize];
int subarr[elements_per_proc];
int partres[elements_per_proc];

// Distribute the array
MPI_Scatter(arr, elements_per_proc, MPI_INT,
            subarr, elements_per_proc, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// Perform element-wise max reduction
MPI_Reduce(subarr, partres, elements_per_proc, MPI_INT,
           MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// Take the highest of the partial max values
result = partres[0];
for (int i = 1; i < elements_per_proc; i++)
   if (partres[i] > result) result = partres[i];
```

Now you have the value of the maximum element in `result`.

Or even better:

```
int localmax;

// Distribute the array
MPI_Scatter(arr, elements_per_proc, MPI_INT,
            subarr, elements_per_proc, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// Find the maximum element of the local subarray
localmax = subarr[0];
for (int i = 1; i < elements_per_proc; i++)
   if (subarr[i] > localmax) localmax = subarr[i];

// Perform global max reduction
MPI_Reduce(&localmax, &result, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: ok, i've got many things wrong in the beginning, after HOURS of trying to understand what was going on i finally got how reduce/scatter/gather works in general. thanks

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu, I would really recommend that you download a copy of the MPI standard from [here](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/docs.html). Unlike some other dry and very technical standards, this one is written almost as a book with many useful examples and lots of explanations.